# Conda upgrade is slow: number of clause count blows up

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

As noticed in other questions, conda upgrade can run for a while while "solving environment" (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, conda freshly updated to 4.6.2)

Launching `conda upgrade --verbose conda`, I can see that it starts getting slow around:

```
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 203458
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 203455
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(889): Final peak objective: 115
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 6211280
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 3847035
```

where the clause count go from 2e5 to 6e6.

How could I make things a bit faster ? Are there some packages/channels known to make the upgrade process slower? I have around 400 packages installed, might this be the issue? And to identify the precise cause? This problem did not always happen, and I don't know if it's an issue on my side or not.

Comment: Yes, most likely the problem is that you have so many packages in the environment. I don't know how to identify the cause precisely though. There are some suggestions in the blog post here: https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/

Comment: @darthbith I have removed a large number, and it still takes more than 5 minutes.  My colleague has >300 packages installed and cannot reproduce.

Comment: How are you adding conda to your shell environment? What are the contents of your `.bashrc` related to conda? Can you edit them into the post?